# Make dictionary keys into rows and dict values as columns with one value as column name and one as column value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

I have the following data:

```
print(tables['T10101'].keys())

dict_keys(['Y033RL', 'A007RL', 'A253RL', 'A646RL', 'A829RL', 'A008RL', 'A191RP', 'DGDSRL', 'A822RL', 'A824RL', 'A006RL', 'A825RL', 'A656RL', 'A823RL', 'Y001RL', 'DNDGRL', 'DDURRL', 'A021RL', 'A009RL', 'A020RL', 'DSERRL', 'A011RL', 'DPCERL', 'A255RL', 'A191RL'])
```

Each key has the following value, a list of tuples:
The dates are the same but the values change.

```
[('-20.7', '1930'), ('-33.3', '1931'), ('-41.4', '1932'), ('2.5', '1933'), ('38.3', '1934'), ('36.3', '1935'), ('37.2', '1936'), ('16.2', '1937'), ('-30.4', '1938'), ('15.4', '1939'), ('29.6', '1940'), ('17.2', '1941'), ('-42.6', '1942'), ('-10.2', '1943'), ('33.7', '1944'), ('43.2', '1945'), ('24.7', '1946'), ('36.0', '1947'), ('-8.3', '1947Q2'),
```

I would like to create the following dataframe:

```
       1930 | 1931 | 1932 | 1933 | 1934 |
Y033RL|-20.7| -33.3| -41.4| 2.5  | 38.3 |
A007RL| data| data | data | data | data |
```

What's the best way to do this? I came up with this roundabout way of joining created dataframes but it is very inefficient as I have lots of data. I would like to have everything in a dictionary first and then convert it to one dataframe.

```
def dframeCreator(dataname):
    dframeList = list(tables[dataname].keys())
    df = tables[dataname][dframeList[0]]
    for x in range(len(dframeList[1:])):
        df = df.join(tables[dataname][dframeList[x+1]])
    return df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dict` comprehension to normalize the given dictionary in a standard format which is suitable for creating a dataframe

```
d  = tables['T10101']
df = pd.DataFrame({k: dict(map(reversed, v)) for k, v in d.items()}).T
```

---

```
print(df)

         1930   1931   1932 1933 ... 1945  1946  1947 1947Q2
Y033RL  -20.7  -33.3  -41.4  2.5 ... 43.2  24.7  36.0   -8.3
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham for your timely, simple & accurate response- I am marking you as answered but I realized I omitted a rather problematic part of my code- my dictionary is nested as follows: ```tables['T10101'] = {'Y033RL' , {'info': 'extra info on data here'}, {'data' : [('-20.7', '1930'), etc.]}} ```. So I'm having difficulty changing the comprehension to suit this peculiarity.

Comment: Can you provide a exact dictionary output corresponding to the key `T10101`?

Comment: `
 {'Y033RL': {'info': {'Description': 'Equipment',
   'METRIC_NAME': 'Fisher Quantity Index',
   'UNIT_MULT': '0',
   'CL UNIT': 'Percent change, annual rate'},
  'data': [('-20.7', '1930'),
   ('-33.3', '1931'),
   ('-41.4', '1932') ] },
 'A007RL': {'info': {'Description': 'Fixed investment',
   'METRIC_NAME': 'Fisher Quantity Index',
   'UNIT_MULT': '0',
   'CL UNIT': 'Percent change, annual rate'},
  'data': [('-22.3', '1930'),
   ('-28.9', '1931'),
   ('-38.4', '1932'),
   ('-9.7', '1933'),
   ('26.5', '1934')]} 
`

Comment: @Bigboss01 You can use `df = pd.DataFrame({k: dict(map(reversed, v['data'])) for k, v in d.items()}).T`

Answer (score 0):

If `tables` is your dictionary, you can do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"idx": k, **dict([(b, a) for a, b in v])} for k, v in tables.items()],
).set_index("idx")
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         1930   1931   1932 1933  1934  1935  1936  1937   1938  1939  1940  1941   1942   1943  1944  1945  1946  1947 1947Q2
T10101  -20.7  -33.3  -41.4  2.5  38.3  36.3  37.2  16.2  -30.4  15.4  29.6  17.2  -42.6  -10.2  33.7  43.2  24.7  36.0   -8.3
A007RL    xxx    xxx    xxx  xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx    xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx    xxx    xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx   xxx    xxx
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for but not quite, the other user nailed it. But thank you for taking the time to respond.